# Pop Over under the botton

Tags: ionic4

Well, i have a problem with design in ionic 4 with Pop Over Component... 
Thanks for you time.
I do the following.

App.Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],

  entryComponents: [],

  imports: [BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
     AppRoutingModule,     

      PopoverLogoPageModule,      
  ],

  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

TS

```
import { PopoverLogoPage } from '../PopOvers/popover-logo/popover-logo.page';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public popoverController: PopoverController) 
  {}


async presentPopover(ev: any) {    

    const popoverElement = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverLogoPage,      
      event: ev,
        translucent: true
    });
    return await popoverElement.present();
  }
```

Html

```
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Bienvenido
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons  slot="end">           
        <ion-button (click)="presentPopover()"> 
            <ion-icon size="large" name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons> 
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I want my popover to be show under my button , but this is presented in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What all you need to do is just pass **$event** in your **presentPopover** method like -

```
<ion-button (click)="presentPopover($event)"> 
            <ion-icon size="large" name="contact"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

I hope it will solve your problem...